# Deprotection of Boc using TAF to obtained free amine group

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I know Boc can easily be deprotected using strong acid like TFA and HCl, but final product is salt of TFA or HCl, my question is that, how we can avoid formation of slat and obtained free amine group.

The proposed mechanism is 
[image]